# Having trouble with uploading files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form where people pick a file, type a filename in a text box, and click save and it is supposed to save the file on the server.

The way i want it to work is for it to:

1) Insert a row in the db.
2) Save the file with the name of the file being the row_id of the db. (ex.38.pdf)
3) Update the db with the file extension.

I cant figure out how to arrange my code so that happens. I can get the row inserted but in order to set the file_name (name the file is saved with) i need to have the extension. Only way to get the extension is to load a library. In order to load the library i need to have $config array (one of which is file_name) set.

Very confused. Might be obvious but maybe i've been staring at it to long. Thanks for the help and good luck understanding it. BTW im using codeigniter framework.

(As of now this code is broken. I've been messing with it for about an hour and a half. This is just what i most recently tried)

upload function that the form is directed to ---------

```
 public function do_upload () {
    $fileName = $this->input->post('name');
    $scopeId = $this->session->userdata('scopeId');
    $user = 'user';

    $date = date('n/d/Y', time());
    $query = $this->db->query('
        INSERT 
        INTO scope_uploads 
        VALUES(
            NULL, 
            '. $scopeId .', 
            "'. $fileName .'", 
            "'. $user .'", 
            "'. $date .'",
            "N/A"
        )
    ');

    $lastId = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->load->library('upload');

    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
    $fileExt = $fileData['file_ext'];

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';      
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|pdf';       
    $config['file_name'] = ''. $lastId .'.'. $fileExt .'';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $query2 = $this->db->query('
        UPDATE scope_uploads
        SET extension = "'. $fileExt .'"
        WHERE id = '. $lastId .'
    ');

    $error = '';

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo 'error';
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());          
    }

    if ($error == '') {
        redirect(site_url('headquarters/scopeSummary'));
    } else if ($error !== '') {
        $deleteLastRow = $this->db->query('
            DELETE 
            FROM scope_uploads
            WHERE id = '. $query->insert_id() .'
        ');
    }

    print_r($error);
}
```

Comment: what framework are you using ????

Comment: codeigniter. i'll put that in there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. Reading the codeigniter documentation I thought I had to include the extension when renaming an uploaded file. As it turns out I do not. Got it all fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i will not explain any code, because you just need a little changes of code.

1. take form input for file name ( ex : name ="filename")
2. form upload
3. if submit button is taken, you must upload file first
4. check fileupload is successfully or not
5. if success rename it with "filename" + mimetype from upload action
6. save "filename" to database
7. if upload failed, go to error message and "filename" will not inserted to database

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the file extension, you want the mime type. Anyone could upload a file that ends in `.jpg` but this doesn't mean it's not some text file with who-knows-what in it.

To get the mime type, you should use the `FINFO` library, which you may need to install.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type =  finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Now it looks like you've done some work to abstract the uploaded file, so you'll want to take the above and replace the global variable with the appropriate full path name to the uploaded file.

Comment: I dont want file extension because i need to be able to link to it

Comment: If that's the case, why do you need to separate the extension from the filename? Couldn't you just save the full name, including extension? Some OS's don't even use file extensions but simply look at the magic number or other meta data to determine the file type.

Answer (score 0):

There's an form_validation library addon for mime types in codeigniter: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/123816/

I'm using it in my projects and works very fine.